# DataType JSON doesn't work with php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, encoding

Here is my HTML

```
 <input x-webkit-speech id="mike" name="string" style="position: relative;" disabled lang="ru" />
```

Then when the field is changes,

This function executes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mike').bind('webkitspeechchange',function()
    {

        a= $(this).val();
        recognizeAjax(a);

})  ;
});


function recognizeAjax(string) {

    var postData ="string="+string;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: postData,
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        },
        url: 'restURL.php',
        success: function(data) {
            // 'data' is a JSON object which we can access directly.
            // Evaluate the data.success member and do something appropriate...
            if (data.success == true){

                alert(data.message);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.message+'hy');
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is my PHP (please don't say anything about the way i connect to DB it doesn't metter right now)

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
// Here's the argument from the client.
$string = $_POST['www'];
$quest=1;


$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "******", "*********") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("vocabulary", $con) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);


$sql="SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE event_name = 'taxi' AND quest_id = '".$quest."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close($con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{


    if ($string == htmlspecialchars($row['phrase']))
    {

 $data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>$row['phrase']);

// JSON encode and send back to the server
        header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
        break;
    } else {
// Set up associative array
         $data = array('success'=> false,'message'=>'aint no sunshine');
        header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
         echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
        break;
    }
}
```

When i change the dataType to "text" in the javasript function - i receive an alert with 'undifiend'

But when chenge it to 'json'.. i receive nothing (chrome debuger see nothing)

I set up all encodings to this article http://kunststube.net/frontback/
And i checked it with simple POST requests - it works perfect.

The problem with json.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does `var postData = {string: string};` fix it? Your string may have special characters, and you're not encoding it properly.

Comment: Also, I don't think PHP understands forms being submitted in JSON formats, so you should get rid of the `overrideMimeType` stuff.

Comment: It do understand http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that blogger, he writes _PHP's json_encode() does *not* work well with nested associative arrays_. It works fine with them.

Comment: @Barmar anyway - it still not works in my case.
Before that i did exctly the same thing that he wrote in example and it worked fine

Comment: If it worked fine, why did you start this question?

Comment: because i changed it to my case and now it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `datatype="json"` bit and change the data bit to `data: { "string": string }`

After that try a `print_r(json_decode($_POST['string']));`. I'm quite sure that will get you your data.

And indeed remove your `beforeSend` callback.

Comment: There's no need to remove `dataType: "json"`. It's redundant because the PHP sets Content-Type, but does no harm.

Comment: Redundant code should always be removed :) I do understand what he's trying to do though. It's a REST service, so he's trying to post raw json without wrapping it into form-urlencoded data which javascript frameworks usually do. And then reading it with `file_get_contents("php://input");` on the PHP/REST end. Easier to make an exception at the php side then to change it on the javascript side though :)

Comment: @DamienOvereem print_r(json_decode($_POST['string'])); is not good for me, because i'll need to return more then one parameter,
the array gonna be something like this in the end:
$data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>$row['phrase'], 'timeb'=>'13.04', 'timee'=>'12.03', 'animation'=>'go_left');

Answer (score 0):

I think the prob is the code `var postData ="string="+string;`
jQuery expects this to be a proper JSON Object.

Next: `$string = $_POST['www'];` takes a parameter named "www" from your post request, but the name above is "string" (at least).

Try either (!) this:

```
var getData ="www="+string;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: null,
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        },
        url: 'restURL.php?' + getData,
```

and server:

```
$string = $_GET['www'];
```

or this (php)

```
$string = $_POST['string'];
$stringData = json_decode($string);

// catch any errors ....

$quest=$stringData[....whatever index that is...];
```